# Top level build.gradle is damaged

Tags: java, android

My top-level build.gradle file gets corrupted now I have this code in my build.gradle.
Is there any solution to solve this issue it destroy my whole project

```
< ? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ? >
        < project version = "4" >
        < component name = "AndroidLayouts" >
        < shared >
        < config / >
        < /shared>
  </ component >
        < component name = "AndroidLogFilters" >
        < option name = "TOOL_WINDOW_LOG_LEVEL" value = "error" / >
        < option name = "TOOL_WINDOW_CONFIGURED_FILTER" value = "Show only selected application" / >
        < /component>
  <component name="ChangeListManager">
    <list default="true" id="ff6b28c6-de38-4fab-88e2-71792ed7adaa" name="Default Changelist" comment="" / >
        < option name = "EXCLUDED_CONVERTED_TO_IGNORED" value = "true" / >
        < option name = "SHOW_DIALOG" value = "false" / >
        < option name = "HIGHLIGHT_CONFLICTS" value = "true" / >
        < option name = "HIGHLIGHT_NON_ACTIVE_CHANGELIST" value = "false" / >
        < option name = "LAST_RESOLUTION" value = "IGNORE" / >
        < /compo 

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```